# Query not executing with dynamic values

Tags: php, mysql, excel, variables, select

I am reading  values from excel sheet in `$number_column` variable

```
$number_column = $data->sheets[0]['cells'][$row1][1];
```

Then make a select query

```
$query_patent = "SELECT `id` FROM `ipoverview` WHERE number ='$number_column'";
```

It is not working. If I echo my `$number_column` I am getting the data at that location.

And if hard code any number to `$number_column`, that query is executing.

```
 $number_column="12345";
 echo $query_patent = "SELECT `id` FROM `ipoverview` WHERE number ='$number_column'"; //This works
```

Help me figure out this issue??

Comment: echo `$query_patent` right before you execute it

Comment: What is exactly not working???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you have UTF-8 as a character encode for your excel file,
and also make sure that you should have utf8_general_ci as collation for your database column 
for more info please refer http://docs.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this.And also `echo $query_patent` whether you are getting a variable on that variable before executing the query..

```
echo $query_patent = "SELECT `id` FROM `ipoverview` WHERE number ='".$number_column."'";
```

The response of the above echo

```
SELECT `id` FROM `ipoverview` WHERE number = 'E1234A'    
SELECT `id` FROM `ipoverview` WHERE number = 'E1234B'
SELECT `id` FROM `ipoverview` WHERE number = 'E1234C'
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got this line:

```
echo $query_patent = "SELECT `id` FROM `ipoverview` WHERE number ='$number_column'";
```

shouldn't that be something like this:

```
$query_patent = "SELECT `id` FROM `ipoverview` WHERE number ='$number_column'";
$rResult = mysqli_query($dblink,$query_patent)or die("something went wrong when executing this query:<br /><br />" + $query_patent + "<br /><br />"+ mysqli_error($dbLink));
// Dot Stuff with $rResult
while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($rResult)){
    print_r($row);
}
```